# Mongoose questions about routing and creating new objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, view, mongoose, pug

I am new to Node, and I'm using Mongoose as a driver for MongoDB. I'm using Jade for my views.

My "Edit" views and my "Show Object" views are looking great. However, I'm getting an "object is not defined" error when trying to create a new object.

I have this in my server.js:

```
require('./models/object');

app.resource('objects', require('./routes/objects'))
```

and in my routes folder I have:

```
exports.new = function(req, res) {
  res.render('object/new')
}
```

finally my view looks like this:

```
h1 New Object
form(method='post', action='/objects')
  .formRow
    label Name:
    input(type='text', name='object[name]', value=object.name)

  .formRow
    label Email:
    textarea(name='object[email]')= object.email

  .formRow
    input(type='submit', value='Create')
```

Is there something I am leaving out? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are using the express framework

you need to pass in the object while rendering the view.

```
res.render('object/new', { object: 'your object here'})
```

you may see http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering for example